# How can I shorten my if statement in a tictactoe game for checking rows etc?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, if-statement

I want to check my rows for x's and o's in a row.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (gameboard[0] == 1 && gameboard[1] == 1 && gameboard[2] == 1) {
     return winner;
}
```

This works fine for me. What I want to know is how could I reduce the amount of code here rather than having a load of if statements to check each column row especially if I decided to make the grid bigger.

I tried doing the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    gameboard[i] = 1;
}
return winner;
```

But this doesn't do anything. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your second variant is not doing the same thing, at all. Was it supposed to? There's no conditionals (and assignment) in it. For a generic grid size you would indeed use a loop.

Comment: try and `if(gameboard[i] != 1) return false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so you know

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
    gameboard[i] = 1;
}
return winner;
```

that is setting `gameboard[i]` to `1` not checking if `gameboard[i] == 1`. But if you want you can do

```
int x = 3, p =0;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (gameboard[i] == 1)
         p++;
}
if (p == x)
    return winner;
```

Comment: No need to continue the loop if the first one's zero though

Answer (score 3):

To check for row win, something like:

```
  boolean win = true;
  for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
     if (grid[col][j] != turn) {
        win = false;
     }
  }
```

would work where turn is holds an XO enum for the player who just took a turn, and grid is a 2D array of this enum (or null).

e.g.,

```
   public void checkForWin(int i, int j) {
      boolean win = true;
      for (int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++) {
         if (grid[col][j] != turn) {
            win = false;
         }
      }
      if (!win) {
         win = true;
         for (int row = 0; row < grid[i].length; row++) {
            if (grid[i][row] != turn) {
               win = false;
            }
         }
      }
      if (!win && i == j) {
         win = true;
         for (int k = 0; k < grid.length; k++) {
            if (grid[k][k] != turn) {
               win = false;
            }
         }
      }
      if (!win && i + j == 2) {
         win = true;
         for (int k = 0; k < grid.length; k++) {
            if (grid[k][2 - k] != turn) {
               win = false;
            }
         }
      }

      if (win) {
         setGameOver(true);
      }

   }
```

my enum:

```
public enum XO {
   X("X"), O("O"), BLANK("   ");
   private String text;

   private XO(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

This is derived from my answer to a similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29436864/522444). Also check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097448/522444).

Comment: How about `win = false; break;` ?

Answer (score 0):

..Or you can do

```
int x = 3, p = 0, i = 0;
while (i < x && p != x && p < gameboard.length) {
    if (gameboard[i] == 1) p++;
    if (p == x) {
        System.out.println("eee2");
        return winner;
    }
    i++;
}
```